# Using Python to connect to Multiple SDE Database Connections

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase

I am writing a script that accesses multiple sde Database connections. I have set the script to include accessing the environment workspace:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

arcpy.env.workspace = r"Database Connections\somedb.sde"

do some python stuff...

arcpy.env.workspace = r"Database Connections\someOtherdb.sde"
```

So, I open then tool, enter my parameters and run it. When it gets to setting the workspace, I get the regular popup window to prompt me to enter my username and password to the sde database.

The problem I have it that the tool GUI runs on top of the popup. Any time I try to click on the popup window to enter my username and password, the GUI automatically pops on top again and I can't type anything.

Is there any way for me to build the GUI so that I can enter my username and password aside from using the `arcpy.CreateArcSDEConnectionFile_management` function? My connection files already exist, so I don't need to create new ones. I just need to log in to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing I found a solution that is working for now. I just went into the validator class and set the workspace environment for both database connections to initiate on tool startup. Now, when I open the tool, I get the Database Connection login prompt to popup twice (one for each DB connection) and I can enter my login information.

Ideally though, I would like to build my ArcGIS GUI to include a string parameter for the username and an encrypted string parameter to accept the password which I would pass along to the connection file prompt. If I find a solution, I will post an answer.